# Redirect .php URLs to URLs without extension

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

I want to make all my website URLs, `myurl/webpageexamples.php`, to be renamed to its non-extension version `myurl/webpageexamples`, if possible in [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) and at the same time redirect all traffic from `myurl/webpageexamples.php` to the new `myurl/webpageexamples`.

I have found several to redirect from PHP to non-PHP like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

What I have:

```
myurl/webpageexamples.php
```

What I want:

```
myurl/webpageexamples
```

I would like to have the SEO score transferred to new `myurl/webpageexamples`.

Answer (score 34):

You want to make sure you are redirecting if the actual request is for a php page, and internally rewriting when the URI is missing the php:

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: I think thats it.
 You are the master.
Does it make any difference to have the check after the request?

Comment: Or would it be better to have the check first and then the browser requests? 
I guess as it is a 301 yhis will transfer all SEO from mypage.php to the new mypage, right?  Thanks again

Comment: It doesn't matter what order, they're mutually exclusive.

Comment: If I wanted (as I will be in a few days) also redirect all trafic from http to https what would I be adding to the code? Thank you.

Comment: How is it possible that works for some pages and not for another? Works on http://www.eldietista.es/buscar but it doesnt on http://www.eldietista.es/colectividades...????? Thanks for the help

Comment: Why did you use `[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)` instead of `(.*)`?

Comment: The `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable includes the entire request, including the HTTP method. Example: `GET /blah.php HTTP/1.1`. We only want to match the "blah" part

Comment: Warning: This looks like the most concise response to this question on SO, but all of the similar answers that I've seen don't account for `.php` in the query string (`GET /blah?tricked=you.php HTTP/1.1`). I believe changing `/([^\ ]+)\.php` to `/([^?\ ]+)\.php` would fix it.