# .htaccess multiple url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a project done ready..Now the client want to rewrite the entire url...ie(www.mydomain/page.php) to www.mydomain/page  ect...

There are multiple pages.say about 10-15 in the folder..is there any possibility that we can rewrite the entire url of these pages at a given shot using .htaccess?

Also the links to these pages carry ".php" and ".html" extensions in order to navigate to another pages..
Now should I erase all these extensions manually or can i change it through other means(eg;.htaccess) 
Thanks

Comment: So you're basically wanting to drop the extension from all the URLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would need to add something to know if it's PHP or HTML, like

```
all .php files becomes www.mydomain.com/p/page
and .html files become www.mydomain.com/h/page
```

(this would need another set of htaccess rules than the one below)

or you can change all .html files to .php so it would be easier..

you can now have all files hide their .php extension like

```
www.mydomain.com/page.php becomes www.mydomain.com/page
```

to do this, on your .htaccess put:

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

I've edited my answer after some researching because you needed to add 301 redirects from the old links back to the new ones so the code above should work now. credits to the answer here: [Redirect .php urls to urls without extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222850/redirect-php-urls-to-urls-without-extension)

Comment: ,Yes the code is working fine provided i erase .php extension(converted all pages to php) manually...                            but now how about the links in these pages?should i change all the links manually by deleting .php in all the files?Is this the only case of dealing with .htaccess for multiple pages?

Comment: you don't need to erase the .php on the files.. if you access `www.mydomain.com/page` on the browser, you will get the contents of `www.mydomain.com/page.php`...

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this in the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

By this you can use urls like:

`mydomain.com/page`

or

`mydomain.com/page/test`

But notice all request will be moved to the `index.php` so `index.php` will be like a router.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Apache provided feature in your root .htaccess:

```
Options +MultiViews
```