# Android volley parse error, Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, json

I'm trying to get from my `database` shop's latitude and longitude, but when i try to get the `JSON response` on my Android app i get the `error`:

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

This is the `JSON` from my PHP file : http://comparateur.16mb.com/ShopGet.php

```
    [{"id":"1","nom":"Leclerc LE KREMLIN ","marque":"Leclerc","adressemag":"106 Avenue DE FONTAINEBLEAU 94276 LE KREMLIN BICETRE CEDEX ","latitude":"48.809081","longitude":"2.362206","lundi":"8h30 - 21h","mardi":"8h30 - 21h","mercredi":"8h30 - 21h","jeudi":"8h30 - 21h","vendredi":"8h30 - 21h","samedi":"8h30 - 21h","dimanche":"8h30 - 13h"},{"id":"2","nom":"Leclerc PANTIN","marque":"Leclerc","adressemag":"51 Avenue JEAN LOLIVE BP 64 ZAC ILOT 93503 PANTIN CEDEX ","latitude":"48.891099","longitude":"2.401926","lundi":"9h - 20h30","mardi":"9h - 20h30","mercredi":"9h - 20h30","jeudi":"9h - 20h30","vendredi":"9h - 20h30","samedi":"9h - 20h30","dimanche":"Ferme"}]
```

Comment: It seems that the problem is related with your server response. You are responding with an string instead a json. I suggest to change the html header to text/json and avoid the strange spaces at the begining of the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the wrong url, add .php to the url.

You're using `http://comparateur.16mb.com/ShopGet` but it should be `http://comparateur.16mb.com/ShopGet.php`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have to either add ".php" at the end of the url in android side or configure htaccess in server side.

For htaccess:
  [Redirect .php urls to urls without extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222850/redirect-php-urls-to-urls-without-extension)