# Redirect urls with .php to urls without .php extension (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222850/redirect-php-urls-to-urls-without-extension)

The redirect using .htaccess doesn't redirect links with .php to without .php

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Even then I could see that the example.com/example.php redirects to 404.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the order of directives. Use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```