# .htaccess throwing outside of folder while removing php extension and internally redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am working according to this question
([Redirect .php urls to urls without extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222850/redirect-php-urls-to-urls-without-extension))
but this sends me to root folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

for eg. my orginal url http://www.website.com/products/abc.php
after redirect it sends me to  http://www.website.com/abc

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic rule that can handle subfolders

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.+/)?([^/\s\?&]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks but i am getting 404 Error, even file exsits on system.. in other words i am getting http://www.website.com/products/abc but with 404 error and abc.php exists on server

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Please make sure that the file `abc.php` is located inside the folder `products` (and that they both *physically* exist, obviously). It works as expected on my side, just tested it to make sure