# Rewritecond by `%{HTTP_HOST}` is ignored?

Tags: .htaccess

I have multiple domains that point to the same folder on my server. The code in index.php page recognizes which domain is accessing it and shows different content for each domain.

Now I want that `www.domain-a.com\sitemap.xml` opens `/sitemap-a.xml` so that each domain has its own sitemap.

I use the following rule in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain-a\.com$
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap-a.xml [NC]
```

However, if I access `www.domain-a.com\sitemap.xml` then the content from the file `/sitemap.xml` is shown instead of the file `sitemap-a.xml`.

Is the redirecting rule wrong? If so, how can I fix it?

I am using Laravel. This is the full `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On


    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain-a\.com$
    RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap-a.xml [NC]

    # browser request: .php to non-php
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222850/redirect-php-urls-to-urls-without-extension
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
    # [NC] is a case-insensitive match
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # First rewrite to HTTPS:
    # Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
    # the subsequent rule will catch it.
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ok, does `http://www.domain-a.com/sitemap-a.xml` work from your browser?

Comment: @anubhava yes if I try to access the file directly with `http://www.domain-a.com/sitemap-a.xml` then the content of `sitemap-a.xml` is shown as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this rule **just above** `# Handle Authorization Header` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)domain-a\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap-a.xml [L,NC]
```

Comment: I tried your snipped and the original above `# Handle Authorization Header` but there was no difference. I also purged my cache.

Comment: Change it to `RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap-a.xml [L,NC,R]` see if URL in browser changes or not

Comment: Still no redirect. I open the page and alwas press `strg` + `f5` to purge cache and refresh. I also tried to remove the `sitemap.xml` file but this gives a `404` error.

Comment: I un-commented `RewriteCond` so that I only have `RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap-a.xml [NC]` but still no redirect. I also tried only `RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap-a.xml [L,NC]` but still no redirect.

Comment: Alright, I tried this and it also didnt work. I now removed my `.htaccess` and the website worked fine (which should not be the case..). I think my laravel app is ignoring the `.htaccess` file. I will try to find the problem here. Thanks for helping me to get here.

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48867772/2311074 I was here 10 month ago. Forgot about it.. Sorry

Comment: oh didn't know you are on Nginx