# How to remove extension in URL with Barba

Tags: javascript, php, barbajs

I'm using Barba in a project with PHP and **I want to remove the '.php' extension in the URL**.

I tried to change the `href` of all `<a>` from `/my-page.php` to `/my-page` for example but then I get 2 issues:

- An **error 406** from Barba in the console when I hover the link
- When I click on the link, the page loads without Barba (no page
  transition).

I also tried some redirect 301 in the `.htaccess` file but I get the exact same issues. Here is my `.htaccess` (redirect found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13225718/16478297):

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

I can't find anything in the documentation, is it even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal No, I already tried (see edited question) but It's still not working.

Comment: Have you also followed the link which says: Possible Duplicate: [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess), both of those didnt help? You didn link to the URL which i referred to so ill posted the link once again.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal Yes I tried it but it doesn't work with Barba.js. It works fine without Barba.js though.